# How to authenticate Google Analytics API with user credentials NOT service accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I need to authenticate google cloud using user credentials since I cannot add service accounts to my Google Analytics property. The user account I want to use has had its email added to each site in GA. The cloud project has Analytics Reporting API, Google Analytics Admin API, and Google Analytics API enabled.

[Google docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#precedence) says to authenticate with `gcloud auth application-default login` and then use

```
import google.auth

credentials, project = google.auth.default(quota_project_id="ProjectA")
```

when authenticating with user accounts. This command throws error

```
403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "analyticsdata.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "method"
  value: "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport"
}
]
```

I found this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-oauth-credential-going-deeper-the-hard-way-f403cf3edf9d) which details a fix. It involves creating an OAuth Client ID and authenticating with the OAuth json key using `gcloud auth application-default login` again but with additional scopes and pointing to the OAuth file. The OAuth consent screen is running in test mode with the relevant user.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
--scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
--client-id-file=/Users/userA/.config/gcloud/ga4_api_oauth_credentials.json
```

Unfortunately I am now running into this error. 956049252304 is the OAuth client ID, not a project that exists in google cloud.

```
PermissionDenied: 403 Google Analytics Data API has not been used in project 956049252304 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsdata.googleapis.com/overview?project=956049252304 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. [links {
  description: "Google developers console API activation"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsdata.googleapis.com/overview?project=956049252304"
}
, reason: "SERVICE_DISABLED"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "analyticsdata.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
  value: "projects/956049252304"
}
]
```

Comment: Have you executed this command yet: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/set-quota-project

Comment: What language are you using I may have a sample

Comment: I am using python

Comment: The quota project is already set to the one I want. I can see that in the credentials file and by inspecting the project object from credentials, project = google.auth.default(quota_project_id="ProjectA").

Comment: Your quota is set for a different Client ID. You must set the quota project after a successful login with a Client ID. Try again specifying only the cloud-platform scope, set the quota project, and then use the full scope list. NOTE: The quota might not be your problem, but might be creating the link between the API and project number.